# Haskell, zip the element of a list with its length

Tags: list, haskell, zipwith

The next lines should show how its has to work..

`[14,2,344,41,5,666]` after `[(14,2),(2,1),(344,3),(5,1),(666,3)]`

`["Zoo","School","Net"]` after `[("Zoo",3),("School",6),("Net",3)]`

Thats my code up to now

```
zipWithLength :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]
zipWithLength (x:xs) = zipWith (\acc x -> (x, length x):acc) [] xs
```

I want to figure out what the problem in the second line is.

Comment: You need `map`, not `zipWith`.

Comment: `map (\x -> (x, length x)) ["Zoo", "School"]` works but not with a list of numbers. The `length` function does not return the "length" of a number (written in decimal notation).

Comment: You can use [this package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/number-length) for the length of a number.

Comment: Your function isn't well typed. How do you know a value of any arbitrary type `a` *has* any notion of length? `Int`, for instance, doesn't have a length. A string representation of an `Int` does, but there are many such representations: base 2, base 10, base 16? Written as an English word? A Russian word?

Comment: This is really a case where you want your own type class that behaves like `Foldable`. `class HasLength a where mylength :: a -> Int`. Anything with a `Foldable` instance has a trivial `HasLength` instance (`mylength = length`), but I don't recall if there is an easy way to express that. Other types like `Int` that don't have a `Foldable` instance can still have a `HasLength` instance. (For example, `instance HasLength Int where mylength = length . show`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the `number-length` package, you can do:

```
module Test where
import           Data.NumberLength

-- use e.g for list of String
withLength :: [[a]] -> [([a], Int)]
withLength = map (\x -> (x, length x))

-- use e.g for list of Int
withLength' :: NumberLength a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
withLength' = map (\x -> (x, numberLength x))
```

Examples:

```
>>> withLength ["Zoo", "bear"]
[("Zoo",3),("bear",4)]
>>> withLength' [14, 344]
[(14,2),(344,3)]
```

Comment: Note that `numberLength (-14)` gives `2`, not `3`. It does not count the minus sign. See the package documentation if you want `3`.

Answer (score 2):

If you transform the numbers into strings (using `show`), you can apply `length` on them:

```
Prelude> let zipWithLength = map (\x -> (x, length (show x)))
Prelude> zipWithLength [14,2,344,41,5,666]
[(14,2),(2,1),(344,3),(41,2),(5,1),(666,3)]
```

However, you cannot use the same function on a list of strings:

```
Prelude> zipWithLength ["Zoo","School","Net"]
[("Zoo",5),("School",8),("Net",5)]
```

The numbers are not the lengths of the strings, but of their representations:

```
Prelude> show "Zoo"
"\"Zoo\""
Prelude> length (show "Zoo")
5
```

As noted in the comments, similar problems may happen with other types of elements:

```
Prelude> zipWithLength [(1.0,3),(2.5,3)]
[((1.0,3),7),((2.5,3),7)]
Prelude> show (1.0,3)
"(1.0,3)"
Prelude> length (show (1.0,3))
7
```

Comment: Thank you for now!

Comment: Note that it will give you a wrong result when applied to a list of strings.

Comment: Not that for floating numbers this will yield a maybe unexpected result: `[(1.0,3),(2.5,3)]` for the input `[1,2.5]`. This includes the dot and also the `0` decimal.

Comment: I would do two functions. I would use `length` for types like `[a]` and the package I linked above for numbers.

Comment: But this doesnt work :                                                             `zipWithLength :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]` <br>                                        
`zipWithLength [] = []` <br>
`zipWithLength (x:xs) = map (\x -> (x, length (show x)))`

Comment: @JanikTi You don't need to decompose the list into `head:tail` to use `map`. When you pattern-match on `(x:xs)`, `x` will be an element of a list, and you will not be able to map something on it (unless the elements are in turn of type `[a]`).

Comment: I forgot Thx, so i tried this but no positiv result: <br/> `zipWithLength :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]` <br/>
`zipWithLength [] = []` <br/>
`zipWithLength = map (\x -> (x, length (show x)))`

Comment: @JanikTi Note that `map` already deals with empty lists correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply a function on every element of a list, that is a [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). The map thus takes a function `f` and a list `xs`, and generates a list `ys`, such that the *i*-th element of `ys`, is `f` applied to the *i*-th element of `xs`.

So now the only question is what mapping function we want. We want to take an element `x`, and return a 2-tuple `(x, length x)`, we can express this with a *lambda expression*:

```
mapwithlength = map (\x -> (x, length x))
```

Or we can use [**`ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) for that:

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

mapwithlength = map (ap (,) length)
```

A problem is that this does not work for `Int`s, since these have no `length`. We can use `show` here, but there is an extra problem with that: if we perform `show` on a `String`, we get a string literal (this means that we get a string that has quotation marks, and where some characters are escaped). Based on the question, we do not want that.

We can define a parameterized function for that like:

```
mapwithlength f = map (ap (,) (length . f))
```

We can basically leave it to the user. In case they want to work with integers, they have to call it with:

```
forintegers = mapwithlength show
```

and for `String`s:

```
forstrings = mapwithlength id
```

Comment: Arrows would work well here, too. `mapWithLength f = map (id &&& f)`

Answer (score 1):

As bli points out, calculating the length of a number using `length (show n)` does not transfer to calculating the length of a string, since `show "foo"` becomes `"\"foo\""`. Since it is not obvious what the *length* of something is, you could parameterise the zip function with a length function:

```
zipWithLength :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> [(a, Int)]
zipWithLength len = map (\x -> (x, len x))
```

Examples of use:

```
> zipWithLength (length . show) [7,13,666]
[(7,1),(13,2),(666,3)]

> zipWithLength length ["Zoo", "School", "Bear"]
[("Zoo",3),("School",6),("Bear",4)]

> zipWithLength (length . concat) [[[1,2],[3],[4,5,6,7]], [[],[],[6],[6,6]]]
[([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]],7),([[],[],[6],[6,6]],3)]
```